# Is it possible to import a range based on an imported range which refers back to the first range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a sheet (B) which functions like this:

The first few columns (A through F) are imported from sheet A.
On sheet B, there is a yes no drop downs and based on the data in A-F, the user will drop down Yes in order to export some other columns, P-U, to sheet C.

My issue is, I want to import the info from sheet C into the same A-F area in sheet B.

In other words, Sheets A and C are exporting data into Sheet B. However, sheet C refers to data on sheet B which is directly affected by the left A-F columns of sheet B being occupied. Sheet C is hidden.

I originally had users manually add referrals onto sheet A once they are moving forward, but it seems keeping referrals on a separate page is desired, so I going in that direction.

I originally had a formula like this, but it returned an Array Literal error:

```
={unique(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/", "'Sheet A'!D3:H1000"));unique(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/ ", "'SheetC'!A3:E1000"))}
```

The circumstance of why I was trying to do this is because sheet B lists client referrals, however, if those clients also gave referrals, I wanted that to reroute to sheet B based on the yes/no dropdown. I suppose the issue is that the formula is trying to run at the same time, but that area is not occupied, so it can't return a result. I'm not sure if there is a way to cause Sheet B to run the second import only once it has values available to do so.

Is there a way to accomplish this using script or formulas? Or, is there is more effective route I should be pursuing in order to accomplish this?  I want to make it easier, but in order to lessen confusion, I don't want to force users to have to input into two referral sheets.

*Adding more info for clarity

The formula I'm using to pull data from B to C looks like this:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/","'Sheet B'!C3:M1000"), "SELECT Col1, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11 WHERE Col8 contains 'Yes'")`

Sheet A to B was like that too until I tried to combine the imports.

Edit: I've edited formulas to match the mockup workbooknow.

Just tried another formula, returning blanks but not the data...

`=SORT({IFERROR(unique(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/", "'Sheet A'!D3:H1000"),{"","","","",""}));IFERROR(unique(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/ ", "'SheetC'!A3:E1000"),{"","","","",""}))})`

Comment: Are you using Excel, or Google sheets?

Comment: I'm using google sheets.

Comment: I've created a copy mockup because i dont have acces to the actual right now. The mockup sheet can be found here:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmUrB4AxDt97IYJlOuPFdbDxClRadi_MIB8etVLKvto/edit?usp=sharing